# ORA-14752: Interval expression is not a constant of the correct type

Tags: oracle11g, database-administration

I am trying to create a table which is having partition on per day basis.
but here the date column is number datatype .

i am getting below error :

```
ORA-14752: Interval expression is not a constant of the correct type
```

Below is the code for create table :

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_PART
(BDATE NUMBER,
REGION_ID NUMBER
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (BDATE)
INTERVAL (NUMTODSINTERVAL(7,'day'))
(PARTITION p_1 VALUES LESS THAN (to_date('20150101','yyyymmdd')));
```

how do i achieve this ?

Comment: Why are you not storing a date in the proper data type?  That is asking for trouble.

Comment: yes as per the requirement its in number datatype. as they are using same format in the report. .can't change the datatype. @OldProgrammer

Answer (score 0):

I think this should resolve your problem:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_PART
(BDATE NUMBER,
REGION_ID NUMBER
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (BDATE) 
INTERVAL(7)
(  PARTITION p_1 VALUES LESS THAN(20150101)
);
```

Comment: It would be helpful to explain why the provided solution works.